# jdbc redshift connection string with custom schema

Tags: jdbc, amazon-redshift

Is it possible to set default schema for jdbc connect string for redshift?
Like

jdbc:redshift://localhost:5439/dev?**currentSchema=test**

or something like that?

Comment: No, this is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

You can't set a default schema in a JDBC connection string.

You *can* issue a SET SEARCH_PATH command after connecting, to set which schema(s) are searched when no schema is specified for an object.

However, it's best to always specify the schema when referencing an object to avoid any ambiguity (as there can potentially be objects with the same name in different schemas).